# Python :: Changing lists in specific files

Tags: python, list, file, file-io

I wrote a code that finds in particular map, files with certain extension (in this case, TXT) and in all found files change one word with another.
But now I want to change a list of words with another list of words.

This is one of the experiments:

```
find_files=[]

searching = ('C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\python programi')
filee = ('.txt')
string_to_change = ['TEST','marko']
change_with = ['testtesttest','max']

for s in string_to_change:
    return s
for z in change_with:
    return z
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(searching):
    for f in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root, f)
        if os.path.splitext(fullpath)[1] == filee:
            find_files.append(fullpath)
for i in find_files:
    replaced_contents = ""
    contents = ""
    with open(i, "r") as file:
        contents = file.read()
        replaced_contents = contents.replace(string_to_change, change_with)
    with open(i, "w") as file:
        file.write(replaced_contents)
    print i
```

I tried to put for loop before `with open(i, "r") as file:`
without

```
for s in string_to_change:
    return s
for z in change_with:
    return z
```

but I don't know how to create it.

Can anyone please help me? Your help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing with those `for` loops... Why are you using `return`? It will just return the first element then leave that function.

Comment: See a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392623/replace-multiple-string-in-a-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop needs to be *inside* the iteration over the files. You can replace:

```
    replaced_contents = contents.replace(s, z)
with open(i, "w") as file:
        file.write(replaced_contents)
```

with

```
    for s, z in zip(string_to_change, change_with):
        contents = contents.replace(s, z) 
with open(i, "w") as file:
        file.write(contents)
```

This uses [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to combine your two lists.

Comment: instead of s and z you mean string_to_change and change_with? 
sorry I forgot to change it...(I change it now)

Comment: @user3540670 no, they're the names of your lists! You could replace `s` with `from_` and `z` with `to_` to make it clearer what's happening.

Comment: I'm totaly lost.
do you mean instead of string_to_change s and insted of change_with z?

Comment: @user3540670 there are four relevant names: `string_to_change` and `change_with` are the names of the two lists, `s` and `z` are the names of *each pair of items from those two lists*. Read up on `zip`, try running the code and throw in some `print`s.

Comment: finaly working! tnx! :D what i need to do if i want to change words in two files for examle in .txt and .xy ?

Comment: finaly working! tnx! :D what i need to do if i want to change words in two files for examle in .txt and .xy ?

I tried in this way but it pick the first file in the folder and change names, even if not on the list of filee
        `for k,r in filee:`
            `os.path.splitext(fullpath)[1] == filee`
            `find_files.append(fullpath)`

instead of

`if os.path.splitext(fullpath)[1] == filee:`
`find_files.append(fullpath)`

Comment: I would make `filee` a list of extensions `['txt', 'xy']` then test `if any(filename.endswith(ext) for ext in filee):`

Comment: `if any(filename.endswith(ext) for ext in filee):` Change it for `if os.path.splitext(fullpath)[1] == filee:` show me a NameError: global name 'filename' is not defined

Comment: I change filename for fullpath...now it change only one file and don't show me any error

Comment: Then you need to look into what files your code is iterating over and which meet the criteria. I suggest you add a `print` or two.

Comment: both files finds and puts them on the list find_files, but only in one file change word's...

Comment: solved the problem ...I just delete any and add for loop before if statement
`for ext in filee:`

`if filename.endswith(ext):`

Comment: That's the same, but in two lines instead of one. However, I'm glad you've solved it.