# How to replace unknown values inside a file in python

Tags: python, text-processing

I go a file which is 10k+ rows and there are values such as `image: "asdasddsg2332qh23h.png"` which I want to replace with `image: ".png"` but there are multiple different value between the `""` so I can't simply target `"asdasddsg2332qh23h"` and replace as that is 1 out of 10k combination and I want to replace everything. Is there a way of achieving this with a python script?

This is what I got so far:

```
import fileinput

replace_texts = {'test': 'w/e'}

for line in fileinput.input('readme.json', inplace=True):
    for search_text in replace_texts:
        replace_text = replace_texts[search_text]
        line = line.replace(search_text, replace_text)
    print(line, end='')
```

Comment: Use `re.sub()`?

Comment: Near-duplicate: [Replace multiple regex string matches in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392623/replace-multiple-regex-string-matches-in-a-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Barmar, use a regex to replace your text:

```
import re

PAT = re.compile('image: ".*\.png"')
with open('readme.json') as inp, open('output.json', 'w') as out:
    for line in inp:
        out.write(PAT.sub('image: ".png"', line))
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW you might not even need python at all, a simple `sed` command will do the trick faster:

```
sed 's/.*\.png/.png/g' path_to_file > path_to_modified_file
```

Or if you want to modify in place:

```
sed -i 's/.*\.png/.png/g' path_to_file
```